# Could not start D-bus, can you call qdbus?

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, d-bus, plasma

I am using fedora 22.

Yesterday it was working fine. But when I opened it today after entering my password it says "could not start D-bus, can you call qdbus?"

When I searched for the solution in net it asked to download some qdbus packages and I installed them and after that I don't see anything expect black screen...

Someone please help me fix this issue. I want to use it badly....

I have important files in the system and i want to access them ASAP....

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem....

Last day I modified the .bashrc file and included 2 lines to source a settings script of a software and that was causing the problem....

Now that i removed those 2 lines my problem is solved....

Comment: This doesn't tell people, coming along since with the same problem, what the settings were and how they caused the problem.

Comment: A common example is [anaconda installer](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1206) suggesting user to add anaconda to path, which alters `qtpaths`. At least, this just happened to me on CentOS7 with KDE.