# FreeBSD KDE. Could not start d-bus. can you call qdbus?

Tags: freebsd, kde, x-server

It is my second day in *nix world and search didn't help me to solve my issue. [This question here is not relevant either.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322527/could-not-start-d-bus-can-you-call-qdbus)
I installed FreeBSD 11 and I installed KDE.

```
pgk install kde
```

I tried to run it like

```
startkde
```

but turns out that I also need X server to run a UI. Ok. So I installed it like

```
 pgk install xorg
```

Now I'm running X with "startx" and then I'm running KDE with "startkde"
and I'm getting

**Could not start d-bus. can you call qdbus?**

[image]

How I can call qdbus? What's that?

### Update 1

As was suggested I edited `rc.config` and added

```
dbus_enable=YES
```

result is the same
[image]

### Update 2

I followed [§5.7.2 of a handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x11-wm.html) and
`/proc` was mounted by adding this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
proc           /proc       procfs  rw  0   0
```

`/etc/rc.conf` was edited and now has three lines:

```
dbus_enable="YES"
hald_enable="YES"
kdm4_enable="YES"
```

Now if I'm running `startkde` I'm getting error:

```
"display is not set or cannot connect to x server"
```

I found somewhere that I need to execute

```
type plasma-desktop #kde4
```

to check if `plasma-desktop` is installed, and looks like it is fine. Not sure about kde. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Have you added `dbus_enable=YES` to `rc.conf`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I did it as you suggested, no luck yet (I updated my answer)

Comment: I'm not sure you can start KDE from inside TWM. Take a look at [section 5.7.2 of the handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x11-wm.html).

Comment: @RichardSmith I followed 5.7.2 of the handbook. If I'm executing startkde I'm getting "display is not set or cannot connect to x server"

Comment: The `/etc/machine-id` part will be a separate question, and I actually addressed this as part of an answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395460/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP How is machine-id relates to qdbus? Do I need to re-generate it or smth?

Comment: If you have `kdm4_enable="YES"`, then X server should start with system boots. If it doesn't there is a problem with it, check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate an `xorg.conf` configuration file then copy it to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` :

```
 Xorg -configure
```

To test it run

```
Xorg -config xorg.conf.new
```

To exit press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Backspace</kbd> then run:

```
cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Also you should have the following line under `~/.xinitrc` file:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/startkde
```

Make it executable `chmod +x .xinitrc`

Run `startx`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Failed to open "/etc/machine-id": No such file or directory
> Option `--autolaunch' requires an argument.
> Abort trap (core dumped)
> startkde: Could not start D-Bus. Can you call qdbus?
> ```

Really, if the error message asks you whether you can run the `qdbus` tool, you should be asking a question that tells the world what happened when you ran the `qdbus` tool.  This question in the error message is there for a reason.

That said, there is enough here to know what is going on, and running `qdbus` manually will largely only confirm what this already tells us.

You do not have an `/etc/machine-id` file.  As I said in question comments, that is a separate question all in itself.  See "[Missing /etc/machine-id on FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFly BSD et al](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396052/)" and its further reading.

The problem here is that the fallback behaviour of D-Bus is malfunctioning.  It is not falling back to non-systemd mechanisms at all.

There are two Desktop Bus brokers in a system running a desktop environment like GNOME or KDE.  You have started the *system-wide* one that runs as the superuser with the `dbus_enable="YES"` setting in `/etc/rc.conf`.  But you also need another *per-user* or *per-session* one that runs as the logged-in user, for these desktop environments to work.  They contact the *per-user* or *per-session* broker, not the *system-wide* broker.  They do this by being invoked with the location of that *per-user* or *per-session* broker passed to them as an environment variable.

`startkde` is trying to run `dbus-launch` to achieve this, expecting it to run a Desktop Bus broker whose location `startkde` can pass along to the desktop environment.  It also attempts to run `qdbus` itself, which if a broker has not yet been launched will also attempt to run `dbus-launch`, passing it the `--autolaunch` option.  As you can see from the `dbus-launch` manual page, this option takes a machine ID as a mandatory option argument.  `qdbus` is trying to obtain this machine ID and pass it as that argument.

You can probably now guess what is happening.

Because `qdbus` has not managed to obtain a machine ID, because it is only looking in the non-existent `/etc/machine-id`, it is passing the `--autolaunch` option with an empty machine ID string to `dbus-launch`, which is crashing that program, which means that no per-session Desktop Bus broker is started and neither is your desktop environment attached to that broker.

To fix this, simply make `/etc/machine-id` be a copy of the D-Bus machine ID, using the `setup-machine-id` tool or move-and-symbolic-link options in the answer to "[Missing /etc/machine-id on FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFly BSD et al](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396052/)".

You'll be glad to hear that KDE developer Lubos Lunak declared KDE's Desktop Bus broker autostart mechanism to be broken ten years ago, and no-one has since come along with a fix.

## Further reading

- Lubos Lunak (2007-10-22). *[I officially declare dbus autolaunch to be broken.](https://github.com/KDE/kde-workspace/commit/9c72c10fb1259dfd4b9944fc4fa07fab3f72a20b)* .  KDE/kde-workspace.  GitHub.
- Bernard Mentink (2016-06-24). *[Trouble running KDE or Gnome](http://lists.dragonflybsd.org/pipermail/users/2016-June/291794.html)*. dragonfly-users.