# Missing /etc/machine-id on FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFly BSD et al

Tags: freebsd, trueos, dragonflybsd

Inspired by "[FeeBSD KDE. Could not start d-bus. can you call qdbus?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395908/)":

I am using FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFly BSD and have some software from Ports that when run complains about a missing `/etc/machine-id` file.  I do not see any such file in `/etc`.

What is this file?  Should I have it?  How do I make it, if yes?

Comment: I think you should report the bug, this needs to be fixed.

Comment: I think the OpenBSD port warns you to create that file when you install whatever it is that wants that

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/machine-id` file is not a standard part of any BSD.  It is a systemd-ism that has begun to leak into softwares that are in Ports.  Usually, the absence of this file is benign, because (so far) there are still older non-systemd-specific mechanisms that most such softwares fall back upon.

Softwares look here for a *machine ID*, a 128-bit number that uniquely identifies this installation of the operating system, consistently across system restarts and (mostly) independent from hardware changes.

One such software is D-Bus.  It too has a notion of a *machine ID*.  Historically, on FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFly BSD this has been found in the `/var/db/dbus/machine-id` file.  Whilst D-Bus has in recent years been altered to look at `/etc/machine-id` for preference, it *should still* fall back to looking at the older file.

The operating system does not come with or create such a file out of the box.  But you can of course make one.

- Obtain the and install [the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/freebsd-binary-packages.html) and run the `setup-machine-id` tool as the superuser.  This will make `/etc/machine-id`, reading an existing ID out of the D-Bus files if it can.  (Use version 1.36 of the toolkit or later to avoid a bug here.)

  You do not need to run this every bootstrap, as once created the `/etc/machine-id` file just sits there for the lifetime of your system; but if you wire it into your system bootstrap, it will also ensure that you have a `/run/machine-id` file and a `kern.hostuuid` kernel variable all containing this same ID.  It also uses/updates `/etc/hostid`.
- Move the D-Bus file into the systemd location and then symbolically link the former to the latter:

  ```
  mv -i /var/db/dbus/machine-id /etc/ && ln -s /etc/machine-id /var/db/dbus/
  ```

  Note that making the symbolic link in the other direction breaks any softwares that expect `/etc/machine-id` to be usable before `/var` is mounted.  Again, these are systemd semantics for this file that you might find creeping into softwares that are in Ports.
- Just make one by hand with a new machine ID generated by something like `uuidgen` (whose output you will have to massage) or `dbus-uuidgen`.  If you already have D-Bus installed, and a D-Bus machine ID file present, this is an inferior approach as it will result in softwares that (first) look in the systemd location seeing a different machine ID to softwares that (first) look in the D-Bus location.

Yes, strictly speaking this should be `/usr/local/etc/machine-id` per BSD conventions, but remember that we are talking about softwares that are looking at `/etc/machine-id` *in the first place* because they are erroneously systemd-specific.  They will not have been patched to look at a non-systemd location for this file, either.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al.. *[`machine-id`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html)*.  systemd manual pages. Freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`machine-id`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/machine-id.xml).  *nosh Guide*. JdeBP's Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). [`/etc/machine-id`](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/gazetteer.html#machine-id).  Gazetteer.  *nosh Guide*. JdeBP's Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395460/5132

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBDS 12 there is no `nosh` package. Instead, just run `dbus-uuidgen --ensure` and copy the generated id: `cp /var/lib/dbus/machine-id /etc/machine-id`. Then `startkde` starts plasma kde.